# RemoteAuthenticatorView error when trying to implement CompletingLoggingIn RenderFragment - No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'delegate'

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I am building a .NET 8 Blazor WASM with MudBlazor in VS 2022. It's working in development but when I deploy to an Azure SWA, I am getting an error on login. Login-Failed is firing with a JSON error. In order to get visibility into that, I am trying to implement a CompletingLoggingIn RenderFragment but keep coming up with the above error.

The documentation for this is basically non-existent.

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" CompletingLoggingIn="CompletingLoggingInFragment"/>
 
@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }

private static RenderFragment CompletingLoggingInFragment()
 {
     return builder =>
     {
         builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
         builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "alert alert-danger");
         builder.AddAttribute(2, "role", "alert");
         builder.OpenElement(3, "p");
         builder.AddContent(4, "Logging in.");
         builder.CloseElement();
         builder.CloseElement();
       };
  }
}
```

It's just not liking this and I can't find the issue.

The .NET definition looks like this:

```
     // Summary:
     //     Gets or sets a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment with the UI to
     //     display while     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationActions.LogInCallback
     //     is being handled.
     [Parameter]
     public RenderFragment CompletingLoggingIn { get; set; } = DefaultLogInCallbackFragment;
```